# When I want my Player to jump he is flying (Unity2d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I want to make my first game in 2D but when i want to Jump, my Player is flying and he doesnt come back to the ground. I don't know why it doesnt work. Hopefully someone can help me. Thank you. Here is my Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
    private float movement = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (movement > 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (movement < 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `Use Gravity` checked on the player inside of Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the y velocity on jump but never set it back to anything else. I suggest that for jump you use [rigidBody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html):

```
rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

---

I also have to say that your first if..else if...else seems to be redundant.

If movement > 0, you do X, is movement is < 0, you do exactly the same, and
if movement == 0, you still do the same even tho you write it differently. (If movement == 0 then movement * speed is also 0). So you could just state that

```
rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
```

without using if at all.

edit: I accidentally wrote wrong line for what to use, fixed it now.

edit2: So after both of these changes your Update function would be like:

```
void Update()
{
    movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i don't know where i have to put that in my code. Could you put that in my code?

Comment: Edited the answer! I did not test the code so let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work but I don't know why i put the c# script to the player.

Comment: What happens now? Does the moving work or is the jumping only thing that does not work?

Comment: The player is still flying.

Comment: Try to change te Add force line to `rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);`

Comment: I've added a rigidbody2D and a box colider 2D to to player. The player is still flying, i don't know why.

Comment: Did you try `ForceMode2D.Impulse`?

Comment: I tried and this exact script works for me. Can you send a screencap of your player GameObject and it's components from Unity editor?